# Add a two different asset path in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I like to use two different assets folder in my rails 3 application. I like to serve from app/assets/ and also from public/template/style1.

---

```
- app
   - assets
     - javascripts
     - stylesheets
       - **styles.css**
     - images
   - controllers
   - models
   - ----
- public
 - template
   - style1
     - js
     - css
       - **theme.css**
     - img
```

---

Layout file

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "styles", :media => 'screen' %>
```

In the same page used iframe like to use styles from public/template/style1/css/theme.css

```
<link href="/template/style1/css/theme.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In production.rb added

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(styles.css)
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/template/style1/css"
config.assets.precompile += %w(theme.css)
```

I run rake assets:precompile and in browser no changes occurred. Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I think your reference to the `theme.css` file is not right . If you state in your `production.rb` adding the path `"#{Rails.root}/public/template/style1/css"` , you should refer to the contents in it simply like this :

```
<link href="theme.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You can consider to stick to the "convention" about the asset-pipeline : place your assets in the `assets` directories .

One more slight detail: if you would like to make an asset resource to be managed by asset-pipeline , you just state this in `application.css` file , like this :

```
 *= require theme
```